# PDF Files created on Terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pdf

I created a pdf file on the Ubuntu's terminal and add plain text. When I use `cat` it shows the wrote text, no problem. But if I try to open the file with a pdf viewer it says that is corrupted and I can't see.
Why this happen?
There is a way of see the file out of the terminal?

I'm new at Linux. 
Remember, the file contains only plain text, and I can normally see the content at the terminal.

Comment: ‘_the file contains only plain text, and I can normally see the content at the terminal_’ So, in what way is it a PDF then, since PDF is not a plain-text format?

Comment: Yeah, my teachet told me that althought tere is the mark of pdf, it is not a real pdf, so it can only be seen on terminal. How do I mark this as solved?